# How can I automatically convert hex to rgb in CSS using Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I always see people typing the `rgb = 1,2,3`, and then using `rbga(1,2,3,0.5)` to create opacity.

In CSS it is much easier to use the hex format, so instead I have `#123456`.
I want to make it simple, I don't want to define a new variable like `--color-alpha: #123456a5`, instead I want to use the same variable. So I would like to have something like

```
rgba(hextorgb(#123456),0.5)
```

How can I achieve something like this directly in CSS? I'm using Bootstrap 5, so I have access to all of its functionality, including Sass.

Comment: AFAIK you can't convert it in css only since you need a hexadecimal to decimal conversion  e.g. `const r = parseInt("#123456".slice(1, 3), 16)`.

Comment: Bootstrap already has a hex to rgb function `@function to-rgb($value) { @return red($value), green($value), blue($value); }` -- you can leverage this like `color: rgba(#{to-rgb(#123456)}, 0.5)` -- note: this is using scss not plain css. Make sure you have `@imported` bootstrap or bootstrap functions before attempting to use

Comment: @Simp4Code That should be an answer, IMO.

Comment: If anything, there are addons for VS Code and Sublime text (and other editors I am sure) that will do that for you as well

Answer (score 2):

Use the built in sass function `rgba(#123456, 0.5);` which will output `rgba([red],[green],[blue], 0.5)`

---

---

Alternatively, Bootstrap has their own function to return just `[red],[green],[blue]` for use in their CSS Custom Properties.

`@function to-rgb($value) { @return red($value), green($value), blue($value); }`

You can leverage this like `color: rgba(#{to-rgb(#123456)}, 0.5)` -- make sure you have `@imported` bootstrap or bootstrap functions before attempting to use